# Architecture of the PlayStation 4 / x86 and V8 cross compiliation

Tags: javascript, freebsd, playstation

The PlayStation 4 is a modern x86 system using FreeBSD.

Does this mean that custom Jit compilers can be used (E.g. V8 JS Compiler) or does the platform disallow flagging arbitrary memory pages as executable?

In other words, is the PS4 close to a desktop PC running FreeBSD or does it have a modified Pipeline / Core OS (not graphics layers, etc.)?

Comment: from what i can gather, it is heavily modified, but it should allow V8 to run.

Comment: Well, that's good to hear. I'd really hate to go and write the entire engine and then have to fall back to a nearly 700x slower interpreter.

Comment: even IE6's JScript was only about 100X slower than C++